# Pronouncing D sound when it's in the middle of the sentence

Tags: pronunciation

For instance. "Daddy"
The first D is a "stop D".
Are the next two "dd's" pronounced as a stop D (Dad+Dy) or with an alveolar flap (like a "flap T" sound)?

Comment: I think your average American will pronounce it both ways at different times.

Answer (score 1):

As said by an earlier poster, I think the kind of medial 'dd' you mention is probably pronounced "soft" most of the time.  "I don't know how he could diddle that little yo-yo (Woody Allen, film MANHATTAN)".  The "trick" for adult learners of American-style English is to avoid the twin perils of making it sound like a double "t" ("dittul") or a semi-glottal ("dih-ul" as in modern Estuarian English in the UK).  It's probably more common to make the medial d a little harder if it is a single d, hence not capable of being divided, even on paper (as in "indent").  I've heard that "double d" grow much harder when it is emphasized for artistic reasons:  "Dad-dee dear, you won't know your daughter (Ann-Margret, BYE BYE BIRDIE)."  Even educated native speakers of US English are aware of pairs that can be confused ("mettle"; "medal") and should be approached carefully.  And for decades writers of certain dialects sometimes show a special spelling for "didn't" to indicate a more phonetic or look-say pronunciation of the word "didn't," which might be rendered "din't" or "di-unt" to show swallowing or glottal-stopping of that single "d."  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your accent and dialect, but personally, I say it like a "soft D", as in data.

Comment: The issue with this answer is that both a stop and a flap usually sound like a "soft d" to phonetically untrained native speakers of North American English.

Comment: True, but the exact pronunciation does not matter as they are essentially the same.

Comment: If *data* has a "soft D", what words have a "hard D"?

Comment: In data, I meant that the "t" is the soft d, and an example of a hard d would be "drum".